# Ошибка при компиляции проекта на С++ IDE: XCODE

Tags: c++, xcode, сортировка

С чем может быть это связано?
ERROR 1:
Undefined symbols:
ERROR 2:
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
КОД ПРОГРАМЫ:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void fillRandomNum(int arr[], int size);
void fillAscending(int arr[], int size);
void fillDescending(int arr[], int size);
void printArray(int arr[], int size);
void quickSort(int arr[], int low, int high, long long& comparisons, long long&     assignments);
int partition(int arr[], int low, int high, long long& comparisons, long long&     assignments);
bool isSorted(int arr[], int size);

struct Menu{
  short num;
};

int main() {

srand(static_cast<unsigned>(time(NULL)));

Menu menu;

const int sizes[] = {10, 100, 1000, 5000, 10000};

cout<<"\tQuickSort\n";
cout<<"------------------------------------------"<<endl;
while (menu.num!=1 && menu.num != 2 && menu.num != 3) {
    cout<<"Натисність: "<<endl;
    cout<<"1 - сортування масиву з випадковою послідовністью елементів."<<endl;
    cout<<"2 - сортування масиву зі зростаючою послідовністью елементів."<<endl;
    cout<<"3 - сортування масиву зі спадаючою послідовністью елементів."<<endl;
    cin>>menu.num;
}

for (int size : sizes) {
    int arr[size];
    
    switch (menu.num) {
        case 1:
            fillRandomNum(arr, size);
            break;
            
        case 2:
            fillAscending(arr, size);
            break;
            
        case 3:
            fillDescending(arr, size);
            break;
            
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    long long comparisons = 0;
    long long assignments = 0;
    clock_t start = clock();
    quickSort(arr, 0, size - 1, comparisons, assignments);
    clock_t end = clock();
    double timeTaken = double(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    
    
    cout << "Розмір масиву: " << size << endl;
    cout << "Час сортування: " << timeTaken << " секунд" << endl;
    cout << "Кількість порівнянь: " << comparisons << endl;
    cout << "Кількість присвоєнь: " << assignments << endl;
    cout<<"------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    
    if (isSorted(arr, size)) {
        cout << "Масив відсортовано правильно." << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Масив не відсортовано правильно." << endl;
    }
}


return 0;
}

void fillRandomNum(int arr[], int size){
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    arr[i] = rand() % 100;
}
}

void fillAscending(int arr[], int size){
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    arr[i] = i;
}
}

void fillDescending(int arr[], int size){
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    arr[i] = size - i;
}
}

void printArray(int arr[], int size){
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
}
cout<<endl;
}

void quickSort(int arr[], int low, int high, long long& comparisons, long long& assignments){

if (low < high) {
    int pi = partition(arr,low,high, comparisons, assignments);
    
    quickSort(arr, low, pi - 1, comparisons, assignments);
    quickSort(arr, pi + 1, high, comparisons, assignments);
}

}

 int partition(int arr[], int low, int high, long long& comparisons, long long& assignments){

int pivot = arr[high];
int i = low - 1;

for (int j = low; j <= high; j++) {
    comparisons++;
    if (arr[j] < pivot) {
        i++;
        swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
        assignments++;
    }
}

swap(arr[i+1], arr[high]);
assignments++;

return i+1;
}
```

Comment: Заметим, что стандарт ваше `int arr[size];` не допускает... Во-вторых, у вас `menu` не инициализирована. В-третьих, и это ответ на ваш вопрос — где реализация функции `isSorted`?